# Error while selecting checkbox and passing value within a List - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to compare two results based on checkbox selection and I wanted to pass checkbox row.execution id ( which has the id for that row in list ) and checked value : true/false;

if i just pass 'e' in the function then i get all true or all false; but when i am trying to pass along with the value, i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined" error. I am confused as to how to pass value along with checked status while we deal with checkboxes within List. Any inputs are appreciated. Thanks.

```
 getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            resultcheck: this.props.resultcheck || false
        };
    },
   onResultChoose: function(e,value){
         this.setState({resultcheck: e.target.checked});
         console.log(e.target.checked);
         console.log(value); // Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined
    },  
 <ListItem justify="between" >
   <span>
  <Timestamp value={new Date(row.startTime)} />
  {" for " + row.runTime + " secs"}
   </span>
  <span>
  <CheckBox label='compare' checked={this.state.resultcheck} onChange={this.onResultChoose.bind(this,row.executionId)} />
  </span>
  </ListItem>
```

Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined

Comment: Please update the code with the *whole* component and update the formatting of it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invert the order of the `onResultChoose` method arguments, replacing:

```
onResultChoose: function(e,value){
```

with

```
onResultChoose: function(value, e){
```

When you bind your function like `this.onResultChoose.bind(this,row.executionId)`, you **prepend** this arguments to the original priveded arguments (in case, the `event` object).

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> ### fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
>
> (...)
>
> ***arg1, arg2, ...***
>
> Arguments to prepend to arguments provided to the bound function when
> invoking the target function.