# Reactjs - unable to put a condition/limitation on checkbox select option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I am trying to use checkboxes in react and the condition is to use only 2 checkboxes at a time and when we use third, it should disable all others till we uncheck another one - so to make total checked max at 2. This is to compare only two results at once.

I am able to get two checkboxes but when i do the third, its disabling all the checkboxes. I am not sure where am i going wrong over  here. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
 var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {

        return {

            resultcheck: this.props.resultcheck || false,
            disabled: this.props.disabled || false,
            enabled: []

        };
    },
    onResultChoose: function(id,count,event){
        var enabled = this.state.enabled;
        // console.log(id);
        // console.log(count);
        this.setState({resultcheck: this.state[event.target.checked]});
        console.log(this.state[event.target.checked]);
        if(event.target.checked){
            enabled.push(count);
        }
        else{
            enabled.pop();
        }
        //console.log(enabled);
        if(enabled.length == 3){
            this.setState({disabled: false);
            enabled.pop();
        }
        this.setState({enabled:enabled});
    },                           

    render: function() {

        var count = 0;

        return (
                <Grommet.App centered={false}>
                    <Split flex="right">

                        <Split flex="left">
                            <Box direction="column" justify="center" pad={{vertical: 'large'}}>

                                <List selectable={true}>

                                    {this.state.execList.map((row) => {

                                        return (
                                            <ListItem justify="between" >
                                                <span>
                                                    <Timestamp value={new Date(row.startTime)} />
                                                    {" for " + row.runTime + " secs"}
                                                </span>
                                                <span>
                                            <CheckBox id={count} label='compare' checked={this.state.resultcheck} disabled={this.state.disabled} onChange={this.onResultChoose.bind(this,row.executionId,count)}/>
                                                </span>
                                            </ListItem>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                </List>

                            </Box>


                        </Split>
                    </Split>
                </Grommet.App>
        );
    }
});

var element = document.getElementById('content');
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), element);
```

Comment: I answered your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41902608/3889043). Do you mind check if the answer was useful to solve your problem?

Comment: @mrlew i am still facing the above mentioned problem where if i select more than 2 checkboxes, entire thing is disabled rather than remaining 3.

Comment: I was talking about your other question....

Answer (score 0):

All of your checkboxes are disabled because your state key for disabled is a boolean that you're passing through to every `Checkbox` component, which means changing that value will change all of the checkboxes. You should be able to change your disabled prop to also check if it's not checked.

```
<CheckBox
  id={count}
  label='compare'
  checked={this.state.resultcheck}
  disabled={this.state.disabled && !this.state.resultcheck}
  onChange={this.onResultChoose.bind(this,row.executionId,count)}
/>
```

I'm not entirely sure what `resultcheck` is supposed to do, but that should only disable unchecked boxes when you have 3 boxes checked.

Comment: this gives the same result as before. disables all the boxes if we choose more than 2.

Comment: Like I said, I can't tell what resultcheck is expected to do. But if your condition for disabled is ```state.disabled && !checked```, that should only be true for unchecked checkboxes.

Comment: The code you provided has a handful of issues, all of which could be creating side effects: (1) You're mutating your enabled state array, (2) you're calling setState 3 different times in ```onResultChoose``` (you really should batch that update into a single call), (3) You're forgetting to add a key to your ```ListItem``` inside your map function. If you don't add keys to elements in an array, you're likely to have all kinds of problems, (4) You're using a count variable that always = 0 as the id for every ```CheckBox``` and the third param of ```onResultChoose```